# facebook messenger bot move position with CSS

Tags: css, facebook-messenger-bot

> I am implementing a facebook messenger bot on a website and need to
>   change its position (bottom at least) and potentially with JS on
>   scroll too.

Since it's implemented using a `<body>` script I don't see how to add CSS that would be active on it. I guess that a conditional JS would be even hard to achieve.

Here is the simplest version of CSS I tried to implement :

```
.fb_dialog {
    bottom: 50px
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Css Position

There are five value of Positions:

static
relative
fixed
absolute
sticky

First set your Position properties and the properties:Top, Bottom, Right, Left. I put your class to understand

Small explanation of values

Position: Static;
It can't move, it is positioned to the normal page. 
Example:

```
<style>.fb_dialog {
    position: static;
    Left:30px;
}
<style>
```

Position: relative;
If you set right, left, bottom, top properties, your element will adjust away from the normal position
Example:

```
<style>.fb_dialog {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;

}
<style>
```

position: fixed;
Your element will stay in the same place, no matter how far away you position it will not adjust away 
Example;

```
<style>.fb_dialog {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20;  
}
<style>
```

**Position:Absolute;**
The element must be positioned with Position:Relative; that's make the element to move only into relative position
but if you use only the Position Absolute without relative ancestor, the element will move on the viewport of page.
Example:

```
<style>.fb_dialog1 {
    position: relative;
    bottom:o;
    right: 20px;
} 

.fb_dialog{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20;
}
</style>
Position:Sticky;
```

This position set the element to stick as you scroll the page. The Position sticky value works for upgrade version Internet Explore and Safari
Example:

```
<style>.fb_dialog {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```

There is another way to put css using Css#idselector. Whatever elements you use like `div` ,`p` and etc. 
You can style your element using id
Example:

```
 <style> #fb_dialog {
    position:absolute;
    right: 20;   
}
</style>
```

`<p id="fb_dialog">some text here.</p>`

Comment: i successfully changed the position of the messenger popup.when i click on it there is this iframe that appears so i can chat and everything is it possible to change it's position too ?